# Missing email using JavaMail on Google App Engine

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I have this really weird problem and I'm not able to find a solution... I hope you can help me...

I'm working in Google App Engine to build my App (lets call it "MyApp"), to test, I have a cloned app renamed as "sandbox-MyApp".

I need to allow my users send a mail with some data, so I have a form where they can fill some information that will be added to the message.

I've working with this scenario a long time ago, but now I'm having issues, because, for some reason, my out-coming mails are not being received by the recipients...

It's a really weird thing about this, because, I can send one or two mails without problem, but after that, they suddenly stop, and after some code-changes, they work again.

- I'm using Java.Mail to do the work,
- I'm trying to send a simple HTML,
- My "from" address is something like "userName@sandbox-myApp.appspotmail.com"
- My Subject its something like: "Hello userName! There is some important message for you"
- The message it's really simple, includes an image logo (served by an https://sandbox-myApp.appspot.com/img/logo.png), an invitation text and a single link to my app URL... (https://sandbox-myApp.appspot.com/)

My code it's real simple, based on the Google Documentation.

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress, MimeUtility.encodeText(senderLabel, "UTF-8", "B"), "UTF-8"));
           msg.addRecipient(javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiverAddress, receiverLabel, "UTF-8"));
                if(responseAddress != null && !responseAddress.trim().isEmpty()){
                    msg.setReplyTo(new Address[] {
                        new InternetAddress(responseAddress, MimeUtility.encodeText(senderLabel, "UTF-8", "B"))
                    });
                }
                msg.setSubject(MimeUtility.encodeText(subject, "UTF-8", "B"), "UTF-8");

                    msg.setContent(msgBody, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

                Transport.send(msg);
```

I've tried changing "from" to something like "app_admin@mydomain.com" and it works for a while, but after some mails (about 5 or 6), stop working too.

Most shocking thing: There aren't any error message on logs... The Cuota Viewer counts every sent mail (so I suppose it must being blocked somewhere else),

I've modiffied the message to omit any URL on the body and It works better, but I need to include it!.

Comment: If changing the content of the message changes whether the message is received, it sounds like some spam filter is stopping the message.  Did you look in the spam mailbox for the recipient?  Are you sure you're not actually sending spam?  :-)

Comment: I've checked a lot of times the Spam mailbox, but it's empty... i've tried to send the mail to different mailboxes of gmail, hotmail, yahoo with same results: no message incoming...

I've tested the mail message using different spam testers and it seems to be ok... It's not spam... I'm working with 3 different messages:

- Welcome to the platform
- Remember password
- Invitation to the platform (sended by an user)

They all fails if the message contains an URL... even on plain text...

Comment: Have you tried it without including the sender label?

Comment: If you change the URL to something obviously innocuous, like google.com, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I've already omited the sender label, but nothing changes... U_U

Comment: When I do some small changes on the message's structure and publish again, sometmes it works again, sending one or two mails, but after that, they suddenly stop... I already changed the url to http://google.com for example, it works the first time, and after a second intent, It doesn't work anymore

Comment: Have you proven that the message is being sent to the mail server every time?  That is, are you 100% sure that your application is doing the right thing to send the message to the mail server, and the mail server is accepting the message?  Or is it possible that the problem isn't in the delivery of the message but in the sending of the message?  If you're 100% sure that it's a delivery problem, and it works some times but not others, then I think you're stuck fighting with the spam filtering policies of the mail servers you're using.

Comment: I think you're right @BillShannon It must be a problem vs the spam policies of Google, because some messages are sended without problem one or two times and then they suddenly stops and after an hour they work again without changes... ... Any one could point me to any document where I can check the Spam policies of Google App Engine? I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I face exactly the same. As soon as there is an url in the mail (like to the GAE application itself) it is blocked... I only got once a mail trough with an url inside without shema but on second attempt that gets blocked too. Log statements after the code are visible and no exception gets thrown and there is no log from the GAE mail api.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is tracked on https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786

Workaround which worked for my application is to not use appspot.com domain.
Register custom domain for the application and then mails to the application using the custom domain work.